# PhpStorm & Symfony - Can't make PhpStorm recognise some services

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm

I gave a bit of problem with my IDE.
I installed recently `doctrine/orm` (with the bundle) and on the auto generated config files I have this:

```
services:
  doctrine.result_cache_provider:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
    public: false
    arguments:
    - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
```

Here, my IDE can't recognise the `@doctrine.result_cache_pool` Service.

While here

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    metadata_cache_driver:
      type: service
      id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
```

He recognise the service  `doctrine.system_cache_provider`

It generates a warning, and I'd like to "fix" it.

As I have all the time I want to develop this app I want to make it as clean as possible (without warning, error etc.)

So the question is:
What is this service ?
Why PhpStorm can't recognise ?
Is there a way to make it recognise it, or ignore this type of warning only for this file/type of file ?

edit : full files autogenerated by `doctrine/orm`

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    metadata_cache_driver:
      type: service
      id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
    query_cache_driver:
      type: service
      id: doctrine.system_cache_provider
    result_cache_driver:
      type: service
      id: doctrine.result_cache_provider

services:
  doctrine.result_cache_provider:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
    public: false
    arguments:
    - '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'
  doctrine.system_cache_provider:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
    public: false
    arguments:
    - '@doctrine.system_cache_pool'

framework:
  cache:
    pools:
      doctrine.result_cache_pool:
        adapter: cache.app
      doctrine.system_cache_pool:
        adapter: cache.system
```

Comment: Do you have the [PHPStorm Symfony plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) installed? Also your YAML syntax is incorrect. under arguments you need to have indentation for `- '@doctrine.result_cache_pool'`.

Comment: Please update your question with your `framework.cache.pools` configuration, typically in `/config/packages/prod/doctrine.yml`. Additionally PHPStorm will not recognize new services in your config files, until after you have warmed the Symfony cache.

Comment: You can point the Symfony plugin in PhpStorm to a container.xml which will usually fix your issue. In Preferences go to Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Symfony > Container and then click on the + to add an xml file. You will find the `srcDevDebugContainer.xml` und var/cache/dev.

Comment: @fyrye Yes I installed the Symfony Plugin (I thought it was this plugin that do the link between config and real classes ?).
As I said the posted yaml code are auto-generated after a composer install (with symfony-flex or some other script that is runned after composer)
didn't know about the recognition of new services in Symfony Cache, maybe that's the thing.
I'll update with the full file autogenerated later.

Comment: @dbrumann Thanks I'll go take a look a this option as soon as I can.

Comment: @dbrumann add the xml didn't change anything.
Deleting the @ before system "id" fix the inspection `missing service` but it's still not linked to any class.
Maybe that's a bug with the symfony plugin ?
I'll let it like it is for now.